# Deserializing Json - Issue with nested parameters

Tags: c#, json

I have the following extension method that I use to deserialize json in c#.

```
    public static T DeserializeJson<T>(string response)
       where T : class
    {
        var s = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));

        try
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);
                ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                ms.Position = 0;

                return (T)s.ReadObject(ms);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
```

This works correctly.

The data contract looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
    public class ResponseProps
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "status", Order = 0)]
        public string ResponseCode { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "lead_id", Order=1)]
        public string LeadId { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "price", Order=2)]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "redirect_url", Order = 3)]
        public string RedirectUrl { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "errors", Order = 4)]
        public string Errors { get; set; }
    }
```

However in certain situations I get an error and deserialization fails.

The issue looks to be due to the data being sent back in some of the responses, which I'm obviously not dealing with correctly. Here's the data that seems to be causing the issue:

```
{"status":4,"errors":[{"Duplicate Application":"Duplicate Application"}]}
```

Anyone got ideas as to how I fix this?

Comment: Why, oh why, do people keep writing "I get an error" instead of pasting the actual error message? *Sigh* Come on, you've been an SO member for 5 years, you should know better than that! Oh, and your [mcve] is neither minimal nor complete nor verifiable. Please fix that. (Otherwise, good question!)

Comment: errors seems to be a list/array in your message, can you try to set the property to `public List<string> Errors { get; set; }`

Comment: @TiGreX neither list or array seems to work as a direct replacement

Comment: @Heinzi - the error thrown by the deserialzer isn't that informative - "There was an error deserializing the object of type n"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `ResponseProps.Errors` should be `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`, not a string.

Comment: As a matter of interest why is it not just Dictionary<string, string>?

Comment: @JohnOhara `[` `]` indicate that it's an array or List. See http://json.org. Consider that the value of `Errors` may be `[{"Duplicate Application":"Duplicate Application"},{"Duplicate Application":"Duplicate Application"}]`.